# Do weights of the [PAD] token have a function?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, word-embedding, transformer-model, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface

When looking at the weights of a transformer model, I noticed that the embedding weights for the padding token `[PAD]` are nonzero. I was wondering whether these weights have a function, since they are ignored in the multi-head attention layers.

Would it make sense to set these weights to zeros? The weights can be seen using `model.base_model.embeddings.word_embeddings.weight[PAD_ID]` where typically `PAD_ID=0`.

Comment: my error: `ValueError: Asking to pad but the tokenizer does not have a padding token. Please select a token to use as `pad_token` `(tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token e.g.)` or add a new pad token via `tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})``

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633368/why-does-the-falcon-qlora-tutorial-code-use-eos-token-as-pad-token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Would it make sense to set these weights to zeros?

As you said, these tokens are ignored during the self_attention calculation, therefore, it doesn't make a difference to make them zero.

Let's have a look at the relevant code of Bert as an example:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel, BertConfig
import torch

sample = "This is"
model_id = 'bert-base-uncased'

t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_id)
c = BertConfig.from_pretrained(model_id)
c.num_attention_heads = 1
c.num_hidden_layers=1
m = BertModel.from_pretrained(model_id,config=c)

encoded_input = t(sample, padding='max_length', max_length=5, return_tensors='pt')

print(encoded_input)
```

The model input consists of 5 tokens (BOS token, two text tokens, EOS token, and padding token):

```py
{'input_ids': tensor([[ 101, 2023, 2003,  102,    0]]), 
'token_type_ids': tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), 
'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])}
```

The attention_mask tells our model, that the first 4 tokens should attend to each other and the fifth token should be ignored. Bert does not use the attention mask as it is, it converts it to an [extended_attention_mask](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/9c336657a92d14c906ed252b5bd251aabd0650fc/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L991):

```py
extended_attention_mask = m.get_extended_attention_mask(encoded_input['attention_mask'], encoded_input['input_ids'].shape)
print(extended_attention_mask)
```

`extended_attention_mask` has negative infinite (e.g. float32.min) for every token which should not be taken into account during self-attention calculation and zero otherwise ([code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/a2586795e577b29c526569b115f0cb4b002db968/src/transformers/modeling_utils.py#L741)):

```
# Please note the values depend on your machine you might see different numbers for negative infinite
tensor([[[[    -0.,     -0.,     -0.,     -0., -10000.]]]])
```

It is applied before the softmax is calculated from the `QK^T`-product ([code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/9c336657a92d14c906ed252b5bd251aabd0650fc/src/transformers/models/bert/modeling_bert.py#L348https://)) and adds negative infinite to padding attention scores. Due to the huge difference in the individual values, the following softmax will assign zero to the padding attention scores:

```py
attention_scores = torch.tensor([[[[ 9.5116e+00,  2.4427e-01, -1.1232e+00,  1.2221e+00, -1.0003e+04],
          [ 6.4593e+00,  5.6316e+00,  6.7172e+00,  7.7484e+00, -9.9928e+03],
          [ 4.6683e+00,  8.1287e+00,  6.1758e+00,  7.5101e+00, -9.9916e+03],
          [ 1.0366e+01,  8.0461e+00,  7.5019e+00,  9.2650e+00, -9.9944e+03],
          [ 1.2470e+01,  4.6752e+00,  5.9156e+00,  9.9091e+00, -9.9891e+03]]]])

attention_probs = torch.nn.functional.softmax(attention_scores, dim=-1)
print(attention_probs)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[[[9.9963e-01, 9.4426e-05, 2.4055e-05, 2.5105e-04, 0.0000e+00],
          [1.5721e-01, 6.8711e-02, 2.0347e-01, 5.7061e-01, 0.0000e+00],
          [1.8351e-02, 5.8412e-01, 8.2864e-02, 3.1466e-01, 0.0000e+00],
          [6.7211e-01, 6.6057e-02, 3.8333e-02, 2.2350e-01, 0.0000e+00],
          [9.2672e-01, 3.8169e-04, 1.3195e-03, 7.1576e-02, 0.0000e+00]]]])
```

Even when you set the padding embedding tensor to zero, the difference to the other values is still so high, that it won't make a difference.

Comment: my error: `ValueError: Asking to pad but the tokenizer does not have a padding token. Please select a token to use as `pad_token` `(tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token e.g.)` or add a new pad token via `tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})``

Comment: what is `token_type_ids `?