# Unexpected error with falcon 7B, running locally doesn’t work for an odd matrix mismatch dimension error, how to fix?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-trainer

I was runing the falcon 7b tutorial locally on my RTX A6000 but got an error with an odd mistmach of matrix mult:

```
  File "/lfs/hyperturing1/0/brando9/miniconda/envs/data_quality/lib/python3.10/site-packages/peft/tuners/lora.py", line 565, in forward
    result = F.linear(x, transpose(self.weight, self.fan_in_fan_out), bias=self.bias)
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (2048x4544 and 1x10614784)
```

I think it's caused by lora. I'm really not running anything fancy literally copy paste from tutorial

Do people know how to fix?

---

## Code

```
# coding=utf-8
# Copyright 2023 The HuggingFace Inc. team. All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional

import torch
from datasets import load_dataset
from peft import LoraConfig
from transformers import (
    AutoModelForCausalLM,
    AutoTokenizer,
    BitsAndBytesConfig,
    HfArgumentParser,
    AutoTokenizer,
    TrainingArguments,
)
from peft.tuners.lora import LoraLayer

from trl import SFTTrainer


########################################################################
# This is a fully working simple example to use trl's RewardTrainer.
#
# This example fine-tunes any causal language model (GPT-2, GPT-Neo, etc.)
# by using the RewardTrainer from trl, we will leverage PEFT library to finetune
# adapters on the model.
#
########################################################################


# Define and parse arguments.


@dataclass
class ScriptArguments:
    """
    These arguments vary depending on how many GPUs you have, what their capacity and features are, and what size model you want to train.
    """

    local_rank: Optional[int] = field(default=-1, metadata={"help": "Used for multi-gpu"})

    per_device_train_batch_size: Optional[int] = field(default=4)
    per_device_eval_batch_size: Optional[int] = field(default=1)
    gradient_accumulation_steps: Optional[int] = field(default=4)
    learning_rate: Optional[float] = field(default=2e-4)
    max_grad_norm: Optional[float] = field(default=0.3)
    weight_decay: Optional[int] = field(default=0.001)
    lora_alpha: Optional[int] = field(default=16)
    lora_dropout: Optional[float] = field(default=0.1)
    lora_r: Optional[int] = field(default=64)
    max_seq_length: Optional[int] = field(default=512)
    model_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default="tiiuae/falcon-7b",
        metadata={
            "help": "The model that you want to train from the Hugging Face hub. E.g. gpt2, gpt2-xl, bert, etc."
        },
    )
    dataset_name: Optional[str] = field(
        default="timdettmers/openassistant-guanaco",
        metadata={"help": "The preference dataset to use."},
    )
    use_4bit: Optional[bool] = field(
        default=True,
        metadata={"help": "Activate 4bit precision base model loading"},
    )
    use_nested_quant: Optional[bool] = field(
        default=False,
        metadata={"help": "Activate nested quantization for 4bit base models"},
    )
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype: Optional[str] = field(
        default="float16",
        metadata={"help": "Compute dtype for 4bit base models"},
    )
    bnb_4bit_quant_type: Optional[str] = field(
        default="nf4",
        metadata={"help": "Quantization type fp4 or nf4"},
    )
    num_train_epochs: Optional[int] = field(
        default=1,
        metadata={"help": "The number of training epochs for the reward model."},
    )
    fp16: Optional[bool] = field(
        default=False,
        metadata={"help": "Enables fp16 training."},
    )
    bf16: Optional[bool] = field(
        default=False,
        metadata={"help": "Enables bf16 training."},
    )
    packing: Optional[bool] = field(
        default=False,
        metadata={"help": "Use packing dataset creating."},
    )
    gradient_checkpointing: Optional[bool] = field(
        default=True,
        metadata={"help": "Enables gradient checkpointing."},
    )
    optim: Optional[str] = field(
        default="paged_adamw_32bit",
        metadata={"help": "The optimizer to use."},
    )
    lr_scheduler_type: str = field(
        default="constant",
        metadata={"help": "Learning rate schedule. Constant a bit better than cosine, and has advantage for analysis"},
    )
    max_steps: int = field(default=10000, metadata={"help": "How many optimizer update steps to take"})
    warmup_ratio: float = field(default=0.03, metadata={"help": "Fraction of steps to do a warmup for"})
    group_by_length: bool = field(
        default=True,
        metadata={
            "help": "Group sequences into batches with same length. Saves memory and speeds up training considerably."
        },
    )
    save_steps: int = field(default=10, metadata={"help": "Save checkpoint every X updates steps."})
    logging_steps: int = field(default=10, metadata={"help": "Log every X updates steps."})


parser = HfArgumentParser(ScriptArguments)
script_args = parser.parse_args_into_dataclasses()[0]


def create_and_prepare_model(args):
    compute_dtype = getattr(torch, args.bnb_4bit_compute_dtype)

    bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_4bit=args.use_4bit,
        bnb_4bit_quant_type=args.bnb_4bit_quant_type,
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=compute_dtype,
        bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=args.use_nested_quant,
    )

    if compute_dtype == torch.float16 and args.use_4bit:
        major, _ = torch.cuda.get_device_capability()
        if major >= 8:
            print("=" * 80)
            print("Your GPU supports bfloat16, you can accelerate training with the argument --bf16")
            print("=" * 80)

    device_map = {"": 0}

    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        args.model_name, quantization_config=bnb_config, device_map=device_map, trust_remote_code=True
    )

    peft_config = LoraConfig(
        lora_alpha=script_args.lora_alpha,
        lora_dropout=script_args.lora_dropout,
        r=script_args.lora_r,
        bias="none",
        task_type="CAUSAL_LM",
        target_modules=[
            "query_key_value",
            "dense",
            "dense_h_to_4h",
            "dense_4h_to_h",
        ],  # , "word_embeddings", "lm_head"],
    )

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(script_args.model_name, trust_remote_code=True)
    tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token

    return model, peft_config, tokenizer


training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./results",
    per_device_train_batch_size=script_args.per_device_train_batch_size,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=script_args.gradient_accumulation_steps,
    optim=script_args.optim,
    save_steps=script_args.save_steps,
    logging_steps=script_args.logging_steps,
    learning_rate=script_args.learning_rate,
    fp16=script_args.fp16,
    bf16=script_args.bf16,
    max_grad_norm=script_args.max_grad_norm,
    max_steps=script_args.max_steps,
    warmup_ratio=script_args.warmup_ratio,
    group_by_length=script_args.group_by_length,
    lr_scheduler_type=script_args.lr_scheduler_type,
)

model, peft_config, tokenizer = create_and_prepare_model(script_args)
model.config.use_cache = False
dataset = load_dataset(script_args.dataset_name, split="train")

trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=dataset,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    max_seq_length=script_args.max_seq_length,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    args=training_arguments,
    packing=script_args.packing,
)


for name, module in trainer.model.named_modules():
    if isinstance(module, LoraLayer):
        if script_args.bf16:
            module = module.to(torch.bfloat16)
    if "norm" in name:
        module = module.to(torch.float32)
    if "lm_head" in name or "embed_tokens" in name:
        if hasattr(module, "weight"):
            if script_args.bf16 and module.weight.dtype == torch.float32:
                module = module.to(torch.bfloat16)

trainer.train()
```

original code source: https://gist.github.com/pacman100/1731b41f7a90a87b457e8c5415ff1c14

---

Related issue:

- https://github.com/artidoro/qlora/issues/100

---

cross:

- gitissue: https://github.com/huggingface/peft/issues/685
- hf: [Unexpected error with falcon 7B, running locally doesn’t work for an odd matrix mismatch dimension error, how to fix?](https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/unexpected-error-with-falcon-7b-running-locally-doesnt-work-for-an-odd-matrix-mismatch-dimension-error-how-to-fix/46358)
- dis: https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1019883044724822016/threads/1128160719339262052
- so: [Unexpected error with falcon 7B, running locally doesn’t work for an odd matrix mismatch dimension error, how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76658481/unexpected-error-with-falcon-7b-running-locally-doesn-t-work-for-an-odd-matrix)
- reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/pytorch/comments/14x1emw/unexpected_error_with_falcon_7b_running_locally/

Answer (score 0):

this ***RuntimeError*** is related to the **mismatch** in matrix dimensions during the matrix multiplication operation in the LoraLayer of the peft.tuners.lora

dimensions (2048x4544) with another matrix of dimensions (1x10614784)is not a valid matrix multiplication operation.OK

for fixing you should ensure that the matrices involved in the multiplication have compatible dimensions but I think give you some advice
at first you should Verify Input Data and after Check Weight Matrix Dimensions

did you Check GPU Memory? or ....

can you use Different Model or Configuration perhaps it can help you
contact me with comment
consider it Debug the LoraLayer . becuse debuging is always help me