# Why do I get UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_idx' referenced before assignment when using interleaved data sets with Hugging Face (HF)?

Tags: machine-learning, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets, huggingface-trainer

I get the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
local variable 'batch_idx' referenced before assignment
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/training/utils.py", line 254, in _test_train_dataset_setup_for_main_code
    print(f'{len(next(iter(batch))["input_ids"])=}')
  File "/lfs/skampere1/0/brando9/beyond-scale-language-data-diversity/src/training/utils.py", line 263, in <module>
    _test_train_dataset_setup_for_main_code()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'batch_idx' referenced before assignment
```

it happens when I interleave my data set:

```
    raw_train_datasets = load_dataset(path[0], name[0], data_files=data_files[0], streaming=streaming, split=split[0]).with_format("torch")
    get_data_from_hf_dataset(raw_train_datasets, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size) 
    remove_columns = get_column_names(raw_train_datasets)  # remove all keys that are not tensors to avoid bugs in collate function in task2vec's pytorch data loader
    # - Get tokenized train data set
    # Note: Setting `batched=True` in the `dataset.map` function of Hugging Face's datasets library processes the data in batches rather than one item at a time, significantly speeding up the tokenization and preprocessing steps.
    tokenize_function = lambda examples: tokenizer(examples["text"])
    tokenized_train_datasets = raw_train_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
    block_size: int = tokenizer.model_max_length
    _group_texts = lambda examples : group_texts(examples, block_size)
    # - Get actual data set for lm training (in this case each seq is of length block_size, no need to worry about pad = eos since we are filling each sequence)
    lm_train_dataset = tokenized_train_datasets.map(_group_texts, batched=True)
    batch = get_data_from_hf_dataset(lm_train_dataset, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size)
    # for data_dict in iter(batch):
    #     seq = data_dict['input_ids']
    #     print(len(seq))
    print(f'{len(next(iter(batch))["input_ids"])=}')
```

why is this happening?

Full code:

```
"""
todo:
    - finish passing the HF block_size tokenization code here so its modular
    - add function to our train code train.py
    - print the sequence length of the data once we include this code
    - create a unit test here to test block size
    - use the re-init code smart ally & brando wrote
"""
from itertools import chain
import random

import torch

import datasets
from datasets import load_dataset, interleave_datasets

from transformers import PreTrainedTokenizer, AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, Trainer, TrainingArguments, AutoConfig
from transformers.testing_utils import CaptureLogger

def get_num_steps():
    # dataset_size: int = int(1.5e12)  # TODO, doesn't seem easy to solve. Either count all the sequennces/rows or have the meta data have this. Or make this number huge. 
    # dataset_size: int = train_dataset.num_rows
    # dataset_size: int = len(train_dataset)
    # TODO dataset.info['split']['train']['num_examples']
    # dataset_size = sum(len(dataset) for dataset in datasets)  # TODO: works on with streaming = False?
    # dataset_size = sum(dataset.cardinality() for dataset in datasets)
    pass

def get_size_of_seq_len(dataset_or_batch, verbose: bool = True, streaming: bool = True, batch_size: int = 2) -> int:
    """Print size of a sequence length in a batch. Give a hf data set obj (batches are data set objs sometimes)."""
    batch = get_data_from_hf_dataset(dataset_or_batch, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size)
    size_seq_len = len(next(iter(batch))["input_ids"])
    if verbose:
        print(f'{size_seq_len=}')
        print(f'{len(next(iter(batch))["input_ids"])=}')
    return size_seq_len

def get_column_names(dataset, 
                    #   split: str = 'train',
                      method: str = 'features', 
                      streaming: bool = True,
                      ):
    if method == 'features':
        # column_names = list(dataset[spit].features)
        column_names = list(dataset.features)
    elif method == 'keys':
        batch = get_data_from_hf_dataset(dataset, streaming=streaming, batch_size=1)
        column_names = next(iter(batch)).keys()
        # column_names = next(iter(dataset)).keys()
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"method {method} not supported")
    return column_names

def get_data_from_hf_dataset(dataset, 
                             streaming: bool = True, 
                             batch_size: int = 4, 
                             shuffle: bool= False, # shuffle is better but slower afaik
                             seed: int = 0, 
                             buffer_size: int = 500_000,
                             ):
    """ Gets data from a HF dataset, it's usually an iterator object e.g., some ds.map(fn, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns) has been applied. 
    Handles both streaming and non-streaming datasets, take for streaming and select for non-streaming.
    """
    # sample_data = dataset.select(range(batch_size)) if not isinstance(dataset, datasets.iterable_dataset.IterableDataset) else dataset.take(batch_size)
    batch = dataset.take(batch_size) if streaming else dataset.select(random.sample(list(range(len(dataset))), batch_size))
    return batch

def _tokenize_function(examples, tokenizer, tok_logger, text_column_name: str):
    """
    
    To use do:
    tokenizer = ...obtained from your model... 
    tokenize_function = lambda examples: tokenize_function(examples, tokenizer=tokenizer) 
    tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(
            tokenize_function,
            batched=True,
            remove_columns=column_names,
        )
    """
    with CaptureLogger(tok_logger) as cl:
        output = tokenizer(examples[text_column_name])
    # clm input could be much much longer than block_size
    if "Token indices sequence length is longer than the" in cl.out:
        tok_logger.warning(
            "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Please ignore the warning above - this long input will be chunked into smaller bits"
            " before being passed to the model."
        )
    return output

def tokenize_function(examples, tokenizer, text_column_name: str):
    """ 
    creates a tokenize function that can be used in HF's map function and you specify which text column to tokenize.
    
    Assumes batched=True so examples is many row/data points.
    """
    return tokenizer(examples["text_column_name"])

def preprocess(examples, tokenizer, max_length: int = 1024):
    return tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", max_length=max_length, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    # return tokenizer(examples["text"], padding="max_length", max_length=model.config.context_length, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")

def group_texts(examples, # if batched=True it's a dict of input_ids, attention_mask, labels of len(examples['input_ids']) = 1000 
                block_size: int,  # 4096, 1024
                ):
    """
    tokenizer = ...obtained from your model... 
    tokenize_function = lambda examples: tokenize_function(examples, tokenizer=tokenizer) 
    tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(
            tokenize_function,
            batched=True,
            remove_columns=column_names,
        )

    # Note that with `batched=True`, this map processes 1,000 texts together, so group_texts throws away a remainder
    # for each of those groups of 1,000 texts. You can adjust that batch_size here but a higher value might be slower
    # to preprocess.
    #
    # To speed up this part, we use multiprocessing. See the documentation of the map method for more information:
    # https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/package_reference/main_classes.html#datasets.Dataset.map    
    """
    # Concatenate all texts.
    concatenated_examples = {k: list(chain(*examples[k])) for k in examples.keys()}
    total_length = len(concatenated_examples[list(examples.keys())[0]])
    # We drop the small remainder, and if the total_length < block_size  we exclude this batch and return an empty dict.
    # We could add padding if the model supported it instead of this drop, you can customize this part to your needs.
    total_length = (total_length // block_size) * block_size
    # Split by chunks of max_len.
    result = {
        k: [t[i : i + block_size] for i in range(0, total_length, block_size)]
        for k, t in concatenated_examples.items()
    }
    result["labels"] = result["input_ids"].copy()
    return result

def collate_fn_train_only_first_eos_token_mask_everything_after_it(data: list[dict[str, str]], 
                                                                   tokenizer: PreTrainedTokenizer, 
                                                                   max_length: int=1024,  # GPT2 default, likely worth you change it! This default might cause bugs.
                                                                   ) -> dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
    """ Train only on first occurence of eos. The remaining eos are masked out.

    Sometimes the model might not have a padding token. Sometimes people set the padding token to be the eos token.
    But sometimes this seems to lead to the model to predict eos token to much. 
    So instead of actually using the pad token that was set to the eos token, we instead mask out all excesive eos tokens that act as pads 
    and leave the first eos token at the end to be predicted -- since that is the only one that semantically means end of sequence 
    and therby by not training on random eos at the end by masking it not unncesserily shift/amplify the distribution of eos. 
    
    ref: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/why-does-the-falcon-qlora-tutorial-code-use-eos-token-as-pad-token/45954/13?u=brando 
    ref: https://chat.openai.com/share/02d16770-a1f3-4bf4-8fc2-464286daa8a1
    ref: https://claude.ai/chat/80565d1f-ece3-4fad-87df-364ce57aec15 on when to call .clone()
    ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633368/how-does-one-set-the-pad-token-correctly-not-to-eos-during-fine-tuning-to-avoi
    """
    # we are training full context length for llama so remove code bellow, if it tries to pad hopefully it throws an error
    # -- Ensure tokenizer has a padding token
    if tokenizer.pad_token is None:
        tokenizer.pad_token = tokenizer.eos_token
    # -- Extract sequences
    # sequences: list[str] = [example.get("text", "") or "" for example in data]
    sequences: list[str] = []
    for idx, example in enumerate(data):
        # Retrieve the value for "text" from the dictionary or default to an empty string if not present or falsy. ref: https://chat.openai.com/share/bead51fe-2acf-4f05-b8f7-b849134bbfd4
        text: str = example.get("text", "") or ""
        sequences.append(text)
    # -- Tokenize the sequences
    tokenized_data = tokenizer(sequences, padding="max_length", max_length=max_length, truncation=True, return_tensors="pt")
    tokenized_data["labels"] = tokenized_data["input_ids"].clone()  # labels is hardcoded in HF so put it!
    # -- Set the mask value for the first eos_token in each sequence to 1 and remaining to -100
    eos_token_id = tokenizer.eos_token_id
    for idx, input_ids in enumerate(tokenized_data["input_ids"]):
        # Find all occurrences of eos_token
        eos_positions = (input_ids == eos_token_id).nonzero(as_tuple=True)[0]
        if eos_positions.nelement() > 0:  # Check if eos_token is present
            first_eos_position = eos_positions[0]
            tokenized_data["attention_mask"][idx, first_eos_position] = 1  # Set the mask value to 1
            
            # Assert that the label for the first occurrence of eos_token is eos_token_id
            assert tokenized_data["labels"][idx, first_eos_position] == eos_token_id, "The label for the first eos_token is incorrect!"
            
            # For all subsequent occurrences of eos_token, set their labels to -100
            for subsequent_eos_position in eos_positions[1:]:
                tokenized_data["labels"][idx, subsequent_eos_position] = -100
                assert tokenized_data["labels"][idx, subsequent_eos_position] == -100, "The label for the subsequent_eos_position incorrect! Should be -100."
    return tokenized_data

# -- unit tests -- #

def _test_all_batches_are_size_block_size():
    batch_size = 4
    # get gpt2 tokenizer
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")
    tokenize_function = lambda examples: tokenizer(examples["text"])
    # load c4 data set hf in streaming mode 
    from datasets import load_dataset
    streaming = True
    raw_datasets = load_dataset("c4", "en", streaming=streaming, split="train")
    get_data_from_hf_dataset(raw_datasets, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size) 
    remove_columns = get_column_names(raw_datasets)  # remove all keys that are not tensors to avoid bugs in collate function in task2vec's pytorch data loader

    # how does it know which column to tokenize? gpt4 says default is text or your tokenized function can specify it, see my lambda fun above
    tokenized_datasets = raw_datasets.map(
        tokenize_function,
        batched=True,  # Setting `batched=True` in the `dataset.map` function of Hugging Face's datasets library processes the data in batches rather than one item at a time, significantly speeding up the tokenization and preprocessing steps.
        remove_columns=remove_columns,
    )
    get_data_from_hf_dataset(tokenized_datasets, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size)
    _group_texts = lambda examples : group_texts(examples, block_size=tokenizer.model_max_length)
    lm_datasets = tokenized_datasets.map(
        _group_texts,
        batched=True,  # Setting `batched=True` in the `dataset.map` function of Hugging Face's datasets library processes the data in batches rather than one item at a time, significantly speeding up the tokenization and preprocessing steps.
    )
    get_data_from_hf_dataset(lm_datasets, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size)

    # get batch
    batch = get_data_from_hf_dataset(lm_datasets, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size)
    print(batch)
    for data_dict in iter(batch):
        seq = data_dict['input_ids']
        print(len(seq))
    print('Success!')

def _test_train_dataset_setup_for_main_code():
    import os
    batch_size = 2
    streaming = True
    # path, name, data_files, split = ['c4'], ['en'], [None], ['train']
    path, name, data_files, split = ['c4', 'c4'], ['en', 'en'], [None, None], ['train', 'validation']
    # path, name, data_files, split = ['csv'], [None], [os.path.expanduser('~/data/maf_data/maf_textbooks_csv_v1/train.csv')], ['train']
    # path, name, data_files, split = ['suolyer/pile_pile-cc'] + ['parquet'] * 4, [None] + ['hacker_news', 'nih_exporter', 'pubmed', 'uspto'], [None] + [urls_hacker_news, urls_nih_exporter, urls_pubmed, urls_uspto], ['validation'] + ['train'] * 4

    # -- Get tokenizer and model
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained('meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf', padding_side="right", use_fast=False, trust_remote_code=True, use_auth_token=True)
    # torch_dtype = torch.bfloat16 if torch.cuda.get_device_capability(torch.cuda.current_device())[0] >= 8 else torch.float32  # if >= 8 ==> brain float 16 available or set to True if you always want fp32 
    # model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-hf', trust_remote_code=True, torch_dtype=torch_dtype, use_auth_token=True)

    # -- Get train data set
    # train_datasets = [load_dataset(p, n, data_files=data_file, streaming=streaming, split=split).with_format("torch") for p, n, data_file, split in zip(path, name, data_files, split)]
    # probabilities = [1.0/len(train_datasets) for _ in train_datasets]  
    # # - Get raw train data set
    # raw_train_datasets = interleave_datasets(train_datasets, probabilities)
    raw_train_datasets = load_dataset(path[0], name[0], data_files=data_files[0], streaming=streaming, split=split[0]).with_format("torch")
    get_data_from_hf_dataset(raw_train_datasets, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size) 
    remove_columns = get_column_names(raw_train_datasets)  # remove all keys that are not tensors to avoid bugs in collate function in task2vec's pytorch data loader
    # - Get tokenized train data set
    # Note: Setting `batched=True` in the `dataset.map` function of Hugging Face's datasets library processes the data in batches rather than one item at a time, significantly speeding up the tokenization and preprocessing steps.
    tokenize_function = lambda examples: tokenizer(examples["text"])
    tokenized_train_datasets = raw_train_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
    block_size: int = tokenizer.model_max_length
    _group_texts = lambda examples : group_texts(examples, block_size)
    # - Get actual data set for lm training (in this case each seq is of length block_size, no need to worry about pad = eos since we are filling each sequence)
    lm_train_dataset = tokenized_train_datasets.map(_group_texts, batched=True)
    batch = get_data_from_hf_dataset(lm_train_dataset, streaming=streaming, batch_size=batch_size)
    # for data_dict in iter(batch):
    #     seq = data_dict['input_ids']
    #     print(len(seq))
    print(f'{len(next(iter(batch))["input_ids"])=}')
    assert all(len(data_dict['input_ids']) == block_size for data_dict in iter(batch)), f'Error, some seq in batch are not of length {block_size}'
    train_dataset = lm_train_dataset
    print(train_dataset)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from time import time
    start_time = time()
    _test_all_batches_are_size_block_size()
    _test_train_dataset_setup_for_main_code()
    print(f"Done!\a Total time: {time() - start_time} seconds, or {(time() - start_time)/60} minutes. or {(time() - start_time)/60/60} hours.\a")
```

ref: https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/why-do-i-get-unboundlocalerror-local-variable-batch-idx-referenced-before-assignment-when-using-interleaved-data-sets-with-hugging-face-hf/69573
ref: https://discord.com/channels/879548962464493619/1197390550245068860/1197390550245068860

Answer (score 0):

The issue happened because llama2 does not have a max sequence length set. So it defaults to max int `1000000000000000019884624838656` . You can set it manually if you google the max seq len for your model e.g., for llama2-7b:

```py
    # - Get tokenized train data set
    # Note: Setting `batched=True` in the `dataset.map` function of Hugging Face's datasets library processes the data in batches rather than one item at a time, significantly speeding up the tokenization and preprocessing steps.
    tokenized_train_datasets = raw_train_datasets.map(tokenize_function, batched=True, remove_columns=remove_columns)
    # block_size: int = tokenizer.model_max_length
    block_size: int = 4096
```

That should remove the issue in the code because

```py
    total_length = (total_length // block_size) * block_size
```

will not be zero when trying to concatenate all 1000 texts in the batch when forming a batch all of which have a length of block size (assumign block size is max seq len or some value you chose).

ref:  https://discuss.huggingface.co/t/tokenizers-what-this-max-length-number/28484